# how to change ui color to color set

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

can someone please tell me if I can change the color on below format using Color Set. For example, Instead of .blue, I want to use my own color set such as Color("colorname"). Is this possible

```
.onAppear {
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "your set here")`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own color like this:

```
extension UIColor {
     struct rickyPurpleColor {
     static let normal = UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
    static let light = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    static let dark = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    }
```

After you can use it like this:

```
        .onAppear {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = Color(UIColor.rickyPurpleColor.normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a static extension for UIColor, like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    public static let yourColor = // ... define any color here
}
```

You can then access this value from anywhere within your app just like the pre-defined colors (e.g. `.blue`, but instead of blue you use your custom name).